# javascript functions executing in wrong order? something about asyncronous?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, operator-precedence

```
function buyabook(bookTitle) {
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    if (status == "unregistered") {
        //alert("unregistered");
        alert("Please log in before purchasing a book!");
        login_prompt();
    }

    function login_prompt() {
        document.getElementById("login_prompt").src = "http://uni.database.ac.nz/BC/Closed/Service.svc/user";
        login();
    }

    function login() {
        alert("last");
    }
```

The problem is that the line

```
document.getElementById("login_prompt").src = 
"http://uni.database.ac.nz/BC/Closed/Service.svc/user";
```

executes last.. I want it to execute before the login alert..or any other things i want to do in the login function.. Im not sure how to fix this.. :\

Comment: ?? How about move the `login_prompt()` function call up a line so that it's **before** the `alert()` call instead of after it?

Comment: You call the function it's in last, so shouldn't it run last? And I don't see any async code here.

Comment: Where do you allow the user to actually type in the login credentials?

Comment: the line document.getElementById("login_prompt").src = "http://uni.database.ac.nz/BC/Closed/Service.svc/user" opens opens a small window on the screen and asks for a username and password.

Comment: And you want to show `last` after the user has entered the info, or just after that small window is visible on the page?

Comment: i want to show it after the info has been entered.

Comment: Well, since the user may have gone for a coffee before entering the information, you cannot expect that synchronous code is going to work. Add the information about that small window (the code), as you'll need to respond to a button click in that window.

Answer (score -1):

I will say that call the login_prompt before making the alert if you want to run it first.
 `function login() {
      login_prompt()
        alert("last");
    }`

Comment: I think then your condition is not true so it is not getting executed before your login function.

Answer (score -3):

JavaScript processes all of the code at once so if you have any functions or variables that are reliant on one another and want to specify an order you need to wrap them functions in a Promise or callback.

Http methods such as get, post, delete etc are asynchronous which means they require time to gather data and any function that relies on them must be called after a promise or with a callback.

Some good reading material:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: There are no asynchronous methods in the posted code.

Comment: The op had mentioned async so I gave him some material on async. He is altering the the src of a document which may be pointing to a i frame if that's the case then async will affect the order of the calls. You can't say there is no async when you haven't seen the whole code. Altering the src that points to an outside resource is async.